# pysqlcipher app fails with 64 bit python and pyinstaller but 32 bit ok DLL Load failed

Tags: python, pyinstaller, pysqlcipher

Built on Windows 11, I have a small app that uses pysqlcipher. I have compiled pysqlcipher with Python 3.8.3 x86 and Python 3.9.4 x64. The application runs fine in both on the development machine.

I compile to an exe with pyinstaller, not onefile, and then package the dist folder with inno setup compiler. With 32 bit x86 python it works fine when the app is installed on any machine.

If I run pyinstaller with the x64 python the app fails to run when installed. I have tested as well with these 2 lines in a test app called test.py which gives the same error:

```
from pysqlcipher3 import dbapi2 as sqlite
print("Test")
```

When building with pyinstaller and python 3.9.4 x64 the app will not run on any other machine and always fails with this DLL error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 1, in <module>
  File "PyInstaller\loader\pyimod02_importers.py", line 352, in exec_module
  File "pysqlcipher3\dbapi2.py", line 33, in <module>
ImportError: DLL load failed while importing _sqlite3: The specified module could not be found.
[8940] Failed to execute script 'test' due to unhandled exception!
```

I have tried everthing I can think of including adding the sqlite.dll as a binary in pyinstaller but nothing works.

The dist built with python x64 folder includes a pysqlcipher3 folder with _sqlite3.cp39-win_amd64 inside it.

Any help appreciated, spent days on it and got nowhere and need to use a library that is only available for x64 python.

Answer (score 0):

I traced this to pyinstaller adding the wrong libcrypto DLL, it was missing libcrypto-1_1-x64.dll and instead was adding libcrypto-1_1.dll

I found which DLL was missing by running the program on the dev machine and checking all DLLs used. This can be done by running tasklist.exe to get the process id and then using Listdlls.exe to show which ones are used.

The error shown implies it is a pysqlcipher problem but its actually the wrong libcrypto that is the problem.

I am unsure whether its a setting on my system which causes the 64bit dll to not be included?